# cannot refer to slider using $(this) inside $().slider({})?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

let's say I have a [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) like so:

```
$(".mySlider").slider({
    range: "min", 
    min: 0, 
    max: 10, 
    slide: function(event, ui){
        // do stuff here on slide...
    }
});
```

Let's say I have a dynamic input text next to my slider to show the value of my slider like so:

```
<input id="slider-value" type="text" value="7" style="text-align: center;">
```

So the full code for my slider is:

```
<p>
<div id="slider-value" class="mySlider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<input id="slider-value" type="text" value="7" style="text-align: center;">
</p>
```

As you can see, initially, when the page loads, my slider has a value of 7. Also, the input text that shows the value of my slider has the same id than my slider div itself. I want the handle of the slider to show that value on page load. If I set the value attribute of the slider equal to 7 like so:

```
$(".mySlider").slider({
    range: "min", 
    min: 0, 
    max: 10, 
    value: 7, // value of the slider handle
    slide: function(event, ui){
        // do stuff here on slide...
    }
});
```

This works fine, but obviously, this is not the best way to go because the value of the slider is retrieved from a database and could change (it could be 1, 8, 4, 6, etc...).

Now if I try to do something like:

```
$(".mySlider").slider({
    range: "min", 
    min: 0, 
    max: 10, 
    value: $(this).closest("p").find("input[id=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]").attr("value"), // setting the value of the slider handle dynamically
    slide: function(event, ui){
        // do stuff here on slide...
    }
});
```

For some reason, this does not work. The handle does not show the value. What am I doing wrong?, Is it because I cannot use $(this) inside $().slider({}) ?

Please let me know anybody why this isn't working

Thank you

Comment: You have two html tags with the id of "slider-value". ids must be unique. This isn't the solution to your issue, but if you do find a way to to use 'this' as you are trying to, the id thing will also be an issue. `<div id="slider-value" class="mySlider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<input id="slider-value" type="text" value="7" style="text-align: center;">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `this` here? Don't think it will point to `.mySlider` because you are just creating a config and sending it as argument to slider plugin, slider is not yet initialized. Try this.

```
var $mySlider = $(".mySlider");
$mySlider.slider({
    range: "min", 
    min: 0, 
    max: 10, 
    value: $mySlider.next('input').val(),
    slide: function(event, ui){
        // do stuff here on slide...
    }
});
```

As a side not ids must be unique of the page. You can use `val()` method to get the value from input element instead of using `attr("value")`.

Edited my answer based on your edit(added markup). Used `next()` method to find the immediate input(sibling) of `.mySlider` and get the value.

**Update:** For multiple sliders use this code

```
$(".mySlider").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.slider({
        range: "min", 
        min: 0, 
        max: 10, 
        value: $this.next('input').val(),
        slide: function(event, ui){
            // do stuff here on slide...
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@ShankarSangoli's answer does address *how* to fix it, but I think you asked *why*.

To answer the question of why `this` doesn't refer to the slider, take a look at how you're constructing that function call.

```
$(".mySlider").slider({
    range: "min", 
    min: 0, 
    max: 10, 
    value: $(this).closest("p").find("input[id=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]").attr("value"), // setting the value of the slider handle dynamically
    slide: function(event, ui){
        // do stuff here on slide...
    }
});
```

But let's replace the names and details with simpler things:

```
object.method({
    value: this.function().otherFunction()...;
});
```

This is the same as

```
var params = {
    value: this.function().otherFunction()...;
};
object.method(params);
```

As was already pointed out, `this` doesn't refer to the slider object, so you need to create a reference to the slider first.  `this` refers to **the most recent enclosing scope** -- in this case, it's anonymous object {} you're creating to pass in parameters for the `.slider` method call.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But why isnt't $(this) refering to $(".mySlider") while I'm inside $(".mySlider")? Hasn't that been always the case with jQuery, for example if you have $("selector").anything(function(){ // here $(this) refers to $("selector") });

Comment: .anything is a function on the selector object, so this is the selector.

Those braces you wrap around the object in your example, .function({ option: optionValue}), are not delimiting a function -- they're creating a new empty object.  That object has only the properties that are defined inside those braces.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ShankarSangoli post:

```
var $mySlider = $(".mySlider");
$mySlider.each(function() {
    var $slider = $(this);
    $slider.slider({
        range: "min", 
        min: 0, 
        max: 10, 
        value: $slider.next('input').val(),
        slide: function(event, ui){
            // do stuff here on slide...
        }
    });
});
```

you take each `.mySlider` and add the plugin and store it as `$slider` to get its value.